# To run a native java application from browser

Tags: java, php, javascript, jquery

I am using php. My question is i would like to run a java app that i created and put its jar file in the client side.I would like to run this jar file which is in the client side or ie, in the user desktop with a button click on a HTML page. Is this possible to run it with javascript or with any other web technologies.

Thanks And Regards,
AlenLee MJ

Comment: `JNLP` is made for this, so just search for `Java WebStart`

Comment: You might want applet, JNLP/JWS to run in browser. For running a desktop user would need to download a file and run it manually.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Java Web Start](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-136112.html). This is a technology to let you start Java applications from the browser that are automatically downloaded from the server.

Alternatively, you could make your program a [Java applet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/index.html), which is a Java program that runs inside the browser.

Comment: +1. One has to wonder how long browsers will still run applets, given the incredible string of security problems recently. Web Start should not be affected, though.

Comment: How do you interpret "native" in the title?

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov: I read it as "client-side" and "outside of the browser" and "standalone".

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov Even if the OP really means OS-specific native code (a Windows DLL, for example), it's possible with Web Start: you can include DLLs in your Web Start application and call them via JNI.